# Filter with specific number of file txt in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem in filter of angularjs. I've try to show the data which condition is ordering=1( it's in field in my file) but my code doesnt working.

Here is my code

```
<script>
  function DanhMucController($scope, $http) {
    var url = "data/cate.txt";
    $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
      $scope.DanhMucList = response;
    });
  }
</script>
```

Here is my html file

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="DanhMucController">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="danhmuc in DanhMucList | limitTo:12">
      <a href="#">{{danhmuc.career_name }}</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

and my data file

```
[
  {
    "career_id": "1",
    "career_name": "Cate1",
    "depended": "0",
    "ordering": "1"
  },
  {
    "career_id": "2",
    "career_name": "Cate2",
    "depended": "0",
    "ordering": "1"
  },
  {
    "career_id": "3",
    "career_name": "Cate3",
    "depended": "0",
    "ordering": "2"
  }
]
```

The "limitTo" just get 12 first element. I wanna get to specific number. 
it's look like sql: select * from table1 where ordering=1
Thanks for your answer

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand. Do you want to print just 12th item? Also have in mind that using a filter in a template is really slow when speaking about performance. You could probably do the transformation in the controller.

Comment: Thank for your answer but I am so sorry about that. I wanna render data which have ordering=1. It's look like select * from table where ordering='1'. and my data file above which I edited. Can you give me a solution for this?
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the update, I am able to answer your question. The easiest solution is to have

```
<li ng-repeat="danhmuc in DanhMucList" ng-if="danhmuc.ordering == 1">
  <a href="#">{{danhmuc.career_name }}</a>
</li>
```

or

```
ng-if="danhmuc.ordering == '1'"
```

if the value is not an integer.

Comment: OH...i have no word to say for your solution. it's so absolute right :D . Thanks you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

On 'ng-repeat' you need to filter array by "ordering" field, with value which you needed , '1' in your case

```
ng-repeat="danhmuc in DanhMucList | filter:ordering = 1"
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: hmm.. thank for your answer but it seems not working...anyway, I've got great solution for this :D Thanks!